# Is it allowed to use numbers as keys in object literal?

Tags: actionscript-3

The following examples can be compiled, but I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere:

```
var o:Object = { 1: 2, 3: 4 };
```

Can I safely use this in my code?

P.S. I know that I can just use Arrays instead of objects like this one, but sometimes { key: value } is clearer than array initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure, you can. The use case for example is `{id:valueObject}` hash map. Key here automatically converts to `String`.

Comment: Thanks or your answer. I've just found confirmation to your answer in ActionScript specification:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/specs/actionscript/3/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=as3_specification126.html